# Matplotlib: Only lines in quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, arrows

I want to plot some data as a quiver plot but just to get some lines, no arrows.

When I use a normal quiver plot

```
axes.quiver(*meshgrid, *data,
            headlength=4, headaxislength=3, pivot='middle', units='xy')
```

I get this picture:

[image]

Now I try to remove the arrow heads:

```
axes.quiver(*meshgrid, *data,
            headlength=0, headaxislength=0, pivot='middle', units='xy')
```

But now I get this picture:

[image]

The plotted lines are fine, this is what I want to get. But some data is missing. Is this a bug (Matplotlib version 3.0.3)? And how to solve this?

Maybe there is a better way to make a quiver plot with lines instead of arrows?

Comment: A workaround might be to set `headlength=0.001`. This is too small to be visible and all data is plotted. So the result is good. But this can't be called a solution.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [mcve].